# Browser bars (address & bottom bar) on IOS safari auto hide not getting enabled on flexbox layout

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, flexbox

Working on a flexbox layout for a mobile website. Since the layout stays fit (flexible to 100%) the address bar and bottom bar stay visible always (no auto hide). Is there any trick to make it auto hide? Thanks in advance